# Recording two files with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Using the recording with tcolorbox (page 147 of the package documentation), I separate proofs from theorems. The proofs of the theorems are in the lower part of the tcolorbcox and appear at the end of the chapter with `tcbstartrecording`, `tcbinputrecords` and so on. I also added hyperlink between proofs and theorems. This works fine (thanks to this forum, mostly). But now, I would also like to do the same thing with exercices and hints for the exercices.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{prop}{Proposition}{% Proposition
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=prop@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=demop@\thetcbcounter,
    label={prop@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=demo-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\demop{\thetcbcounter}{demo-\thetcbcounter.tex}}
    }
    {Proposition}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\demop}{mm}{% Démonstration d'une proposition
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Démonstration de la proposition~\ref{prop@#1},
    hypertarget=demop@#1,hyperlink=prop@#1
    }
    {\input{#2}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{exer}{Exercice}{% Exercice avec indication
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=exer@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=indication@\thetcbcounter,
    label={exer@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=indic-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\indication{\thetcbcounter}{indic-\thetcbcounter.tex}}
    }
    {Exercice}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\indication}{mm}{% Indication pour un exercice
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Indication pour l'exercice~\ref{exer@#1},
    hypertarget=indication@#1,hyperlink=exer@#1
}
{\input{#2}}



\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\chapter{Premier}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}
        Premier théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{exer}{}{}
        Un premier exercice
        \tcblower
        Une indication
    \end{exer}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}
        Deuxième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{exer}{}{}
        Un deuxième exercice
        \tcblower
        Une indication
    \end{exer}

\tcbstoprecording

\newpage

\begin{center}
    {\Huge\bfseries Démonstrations}
\end{center}

\tcbinputrecords

\newpage

\begin{center}
    {\Huge\bfseries Indications pour les exercices}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But of course, the proofs of theorems and hints for the exercises are mixed and I don't want that. I would like the proofs to be after "Démonstrations" page, and the hints to be after " Indications pour les exercices" page.
So, I guess I need two separate recording files that I could call in the correct page.
How could I do that (I don't even know if it's possible)

Comment: check the documentation, 8.1 Macros. The commands have an optional argument.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. I already looked at that but I didn't understand how to do what I want, sorry. I see that I can choose the file name for \tcbstartrecording. So I can do \tcbsartrecording[\proofs.records] and  \tcbsartrecording[\hints.records] but how do I manage to  record the proofs in file \proof.records and the hints in file \hints.records? I guess I have to do that in my macros but how?

Comment: Although you can fix the name of recording file, the `record` command only writes in default one. I've also tested alternating stoprecording and startrecording but only the last record is collected. I think you will need to adapt these macros. But I don't know how.

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi Maybe Ulrike will tell us how to do that?

Comment: Yesterady I filled an issue in `Tcolorbox` development site (https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/239) and there are two different codes to test. I will wait to being them included in new versions to place them as an answer.

Comment: Ok @Ignasi Thé solution given by cfr works great,  but I have to it in every chapter

Comment: @Didier You could probably automate it, but if `tcolorbox` is getting a solution, that's bound to be preferable. If it looks like the fix might be a while, it might be worth it. I agree my method is a pain, even though it has a certain strictly theoretical simplicity I like (mostly because I rarely think of such 'tricks', which other people seem to drop them into answers and comments all the time!).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using another file for writing (which draws on a limited resource), you can just skip the lines of the `.records` file you don't want.

```
\let\indicationsaved\indication
\def\indication#1#2{\relax}

\tcbinputrecords
```

This saves the meaning of `\indications` and then redefines it to do nothing, so hints recorded in the `.records` file will be skipped when `\tcbinputrecords` is called, leaving just the proofs.

```
\let\indication\indicationsaved
\def\demop#1#2{\relax}

\tcbinputrecords
```

This restores the original meaning of `\indications` and redefines `\demop` to do nothing, so proofs recorded in the `.records` file will be skipped, leaving just the hints.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{prop}{Proposition}{% Proposition
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=prop@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=demop@\thetcbcounter,
    label={prop@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=demo-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\demop{\thetcbcounter}{demo-\thetcbcounter.tex}}
    }
    {Proposition}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\demop}{mm}{% Démonstration d'une proposition
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Démonstration de la proposition~\ref{prop@#1},
    hypertarget=demop@#1,hyperlink=prop@#1
    }
    {\input{#2}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{exer}{Exercice}{% Exercice avec indication
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=exer@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=indication@\thetcbcounter,
    label={exer@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=indic-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\indication{\thetcbcounter}{indic-\thetcbcounter.tex}}
    }
    {Exercice}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\indication}{mm}{% Indication pour un exercice
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Indication pour l'exercice~\ref{exer@#1},
    hypertarget=indication@#1,hyperlink=exer@#1
}
{\input{#2}}



\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\chapter{Premier}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}
        Premier théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{exer}{}{}
        Un premier exercice
        \tcblower
        Une indication
    \end{exer}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}
        Deuxième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{exer}{}{}
        Un deuxième exercice
        \tcblower
        Une indication
    \end{exer}

\tcbstoprecording

\newpage

\begin{center}
    {\Huge\bfseries Démonstrations}
\end{center}

\let\indicationsaved\indication
\def\indication#1#2{\relax}

\tcbinputrecords

\newpage

\begin{center}
    {\Huge\bfseries Indications pour les exercices}
\end{center}

\let\indication\indicationsaved
\def\demop#1#2{\relax}

\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

[image: separated hints and proofs]

Comment: Thanks a lot @cfr It works perfectly fine. Just to know: was it even possible to save proofs and hints in different files?

Comment: @Didier The honest answer is, I don't know. I tried to figure out how to do it and I certainly created lots of files, but the code was really beyond me and, since this worked and saved on `\write`s, I didn't pursue the mess I'd made ;). I believe I got it to record them in different files, but I couldn't figure out how to get more than one of each into each file. That is, I only ever got the last of each type recorded. I think overcoming that requires rewriting the internal stuff and that's over my head.

Comment: Thank you @cfr Your solution works perfectly fine and that’s enough for me. If it was simple to write on two different files, I may have done that way, but since it is not

Comment: @Didier You could look at the suggestions on GitHub, but my solution may be less prone to bugs just because it doesn't try to do anything complicated!

Comment: I prefer your solution. At least, I understand it